# wierd! require('stylus') in .vue file Failed

Tags: vue.js, require, vue-component, stylus

I trid to use stylus in `test.vue` file

```
let stylus = require('stylus')
console.log(stylus)
```

But failed.

```
This dependency was not found:
* fs in ./~/.0.54.5@stylus/lib/utils.js, ./~/.0.54.5@stylus/lib/middleware.js and 12 others
To install it, you can run: npm install --save fs
This relative module was not found:
* ./lib-cov/stylus in ./~/.0.54.5@stylus/index.js
```

I touched a new `test.js` file and require('stylus') in it,It's ok.
so werid.

```
"vue": "^2.3.3",
"stylus": "^0.54.5",
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Try adding node: { fs: 'empty' } in webpack config file.

Comment: @qkr I add it in webpack.base.conf.js, but it doesn't work.

Comment: If you want to use stylus in `.vue` files, you will need loader for webpack, It's called `stylus-loader`

Comment: @BelminBedak I use `npm install stylus-loader` and add `{test: /\.styl$/,loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!stylus-loader'}` in webpack.base.conf.js. still doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think you have to explicitly include it as rule in webpack file - just add `lang="stylus"` attribute on the `style` section in `.vue` file.

Comment: @BelminBedak sorry, maybe i don't explain that clearly. I want to use stylus's API in JS, not in <style>

Comment: it seems like the stylus Javascript api cannot run in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Stylus javascript API cannot run in the browser because it is depending on the fs module from NodeJs :
https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/fs.html